# How do I redirect GC to log4j2?

Tags: java, log4j2

I have log4j2 set up and am using org.apache.logging.log4j.io.IoBuilder to redirect stdout and stderr to my log like so:

```
System.setOut(IoBuilder.forLogger(LogManager.getLogger("out")).setLevel(Level.INFO).buildPrintStream());
System.setErr(IoBuilder.forLogger(LogManager.getLogger("err")).setLevel(Level.ERROR).buildPrintStream());
```

If in the code there is something like System.out.println("this is a test"); I get the expected output of:

```
15:15:43.817 [main] INFO  out - this is a test
```

given my log config.

However, if I add GC to the program: -XX:+PrintGCDetails I would expect something similar but I am getting e.g. this:

```
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 49152K->6129K(57344K)] 49152K->6137K(188416K), 0.1090832 secs] [Times: user=0.16 sys=0.00, real=0.11 secs]
```

My question is why isn't the GC getting piped through my logger? Surely it must be sent to either the stdout or stderr?

Comment: GC executed from JVM

Answer (score 2):

The GC is executed by the VM which is below of your program.

The VM uses its own logging which is completely independent of the Java logging.